# Initialize input value php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have create a form to edit the image and already get the data from database. But it doesn't have the initialize value of that slider.

Here is the code :

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Upload image</label>
    <img src="<?=$value['slider_link']?>" alt="<?=$value['slider_name']?>" style="width: 90%;">
    <input name="file" type="file" class="form-control" id="file" value="<?=$value['slider_link']?>">
</fieldset>
```

[image: theresult]

As you can see, the image was loaded. But the value inside the input wasn't call. It suppose to have Database.png into the input.

How can I fix this?

Comment: file input will show name only when a file got selected by clicking browse button

Comment: You can't pre populate a file input fields value because of security reason, [more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16365668/8566549).

Comment: so it is impossible right?

Comment: Yes it is impossible

Comment: You're welcome, you could also consider using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19721743/8566549) method instead

Answer (score 0):

We can't initialized the input file. moreover you if you want the file name on submit you can store it onto the hidden variable.